# /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: FROM:: not found

Tags: apt, grub2, dpkg

I have Xubuntu 18.04.3, and whenever I try to install a package through `apt-get` I get the following message.

```
Removing linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic (5.0.0-31.33~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-31-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 35: /etc/default/grub: FROM:: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Contents of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="persistent"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

FROM:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
TO:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever kernel or kernel modules are updated, DPKG [sources](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/04/what-is-sourcing-file.html?m=1) the GRUB. It seems that you were following [How to disable IPv6 address on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) due to which you modified the GRUB file located in ***/etc/default***. Originally, you were supposed to edit the corresponding lines in that file but you ended up appending those lines. And because of appending those lines `FROM:` and `TO:` were also got written there which of course isn't a valid entry for GRUB.

To fix the issue, you need to delete those lines. Edit the file in a text editor with elevated privileges

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And delete last 6 lines, i.e. from line 35 to 40.

If you want to do what that article was telling to do, edit the lines 10 and 11 accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like such an idiot for doing this kind of mistake. one thing I forgot to mention is that the error didn't appear right after editing the GRUB file. It only appeared after I Tried to uninstall some packages through package manager. Is it because DPKG sourced the GRUB only then?

Comment: @Nadi726 Yes. GRUB file is sourced whenever some information relevant to GRUB is updated, for example, kernel. You can source GRUB whenever you need just by running `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Reconfigure package cache

The database must have got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfigure the cache

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**Option 2**: Correct broken dependencies

Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

```
sudo apt install -f
```

**Option 3**: Remove post info files of the troublesome packages

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/* /tmp
```

Comment: `apt-get install -f` doesn't install packages forcefully. `f` is single character flag for `--fix-broken`.

Comment: The first 2 doesn't work, and when trying the 3rd it says "Argument list too long". I tried using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942422/moving-large-number-of-files but it seemed to make the problem worse, so I reverted the changes.